# How do I list all installed packages from the command line in bash / osX

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, bash, shell

What is the `-bash` command to list all the packages installed locally on my machine?

I am using osX.

I tried the following so far:

1. `dpkg -l` - doesn't work.
2. `apt --installed list` - doesn't work.
3. `pkgutil --pkgs` - lists only those installed with Apple installer. I need all those installed with `npm`.
4. `npm list` - works.
5. `npm list -g --depth=0` - works.
6. `` ls `npm root -g` `` - works.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`pkgutil --pkgs` will list all the packages installed with Apple's installer