# How do I see a list of installed applications, packages, programs, etc. in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, installation

For instance, I installed Python, Node, and Homebrew. They don't show up in /Applications, they don't create .app files, and they don't show up in my uninstaller apps.

I am losing track of what I've installed, so is there any way to check?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this If none of the method as mentioned in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/959767/how-do-i-list-all-installed-packages-from-the-command-line-in-bash-osx) worked for you.

```
system_profiler -detailLevel full > packages.txt
```

Read the manpage further for much precise information.

Answer (score 2):

macOS does not require software packages to be registered with the system, nor does it force you to use a single approved package manager (or any package manager at all). So there is no straightforward way to find out what all you you’ve installed, especially if you’ve installed stuff by hand without using the App Store or Installer.app, or Homebrew or MacPorts or Fink or whatever.

Comment: That's unfortunate because I really liked how I can see a list of installed programs in Windows, regardless of whether it's a command-line tool, or game, or redistributable, etc.